# Windows Server 2003 randomly hangs during it's weekly reboot

Tags: windows-server-2003, hung

No logging tools can help me as to these tools absolutely nothing has hung, and no other logs show anything unusual. I can still run the teamviewer app which can force a 'Hard Reboot'. Is there any way I can invoke this reboot myself with a scheduled script?

I don't want to be so familiar to it's owner - Apart from this, I would never have to speak to him!

Once it didn't happen for 4 months - It has happened twice in the last 3 months. I could not predict when it happens again.

This machine has had no disk errors at all, so all the caching and shutdown prep on the drive has been done before the hang.

Comment: Interesting to know, did you finish to find the reason-s?

Comment: Bad capacitor on motherboard - Replaced that and been fine ever since.

Answer (score 1):

Bad capacitor on motherboard - One of them had bulged and leaked on the top. Replaced that and been fine ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run something like [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) that will test the memory? I suspect that that you may have some memory that is faulty.